# iterating through a 2d array and listing only 1s which are connected

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, path

Thank you for the replies...

Hi
i would need a function which takes a 2d array or map with filled with 0 and 1. where 1 represent the walkable ground and 0 is the wall. i need an algorithm which iterates trough the whole array where its walkable... and prints out only the walkable surface and the direction how it walks it trough.. something like in the attached file.

So far i managged to print the walkable surface of an array using flood fill, but didnt managed to print the directions.
Could you help me with that , i am working in Java
Am i on the right direction with flood fill? is it possible to print how the algorithm iterates trough the walkable surface?

[image]

I already have the output where the walkable path is changed from 1 to 2 s , but still need the direction printing....

The Code so far

```
class Solution {
private void dfs(int row, int col, 
 int[][] ans,
 int[][] image, 
 int newColor, int delRow[], int delCol[],
 int iniColor) {
    

    ans[row][col] = newColor; 
    int n = image.length;
    int m = image[0].length; 
    
    for(int i = 0;i<4;i++) {
        int nrow = row + delRow[i]; 
        int ncol = col + delCol[i]; 
                 
        if(nrow>=0 && nrow<n && ncol>=0 && ncol < m && 
        image[nrow][ncol] == iniColor && ans[nrow][ncol] != newColor) {
            dfs(nrow, ncol, ans, image, newColor, delRow, delCol, iniColor); 
            if(nrow == 1) {
                System.out.println("Right");
            }
            if(nrow == -1) {
                System.out.println("Left");
            }
            if(ncol == 1) {
                System.out.println("Up");
            }
            if(ncol == -1) {
                System.out.println("Down");
            }
            }
    }
}
public int[][] floodFill(int[][] image, int sr, int sc, int newColor)
{
    
    int iniColor = image[sr][sc]; 
    int[][] ans = image; 
    
    int delRow[] = {-1, 0, +1, 0};
    int delCol[] = {0, +1, 0, -1}; 
    dfs(sr, sc, ans, image, newColor, delRow, delCol, iniColor); 
    return ans;  
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[][] image =  {
        {1,1,1,0,1,1},
        {0,0,1,0,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {1,1,1,0,1,1}
    };

      
    Solution obj = new Solution();
    int[][] ans = obj.floodFill(image, 0, 0, 2);
    for(int i = 0; i < ans.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < ans[i].length; j++)
            System.out.print(ans[i][j] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you looking for a flood fill?

Comment: Yes, as @JasonAller mentions, a flood-fill would work fine here, and can be done using recursion.

Comment: Thank You for the quick reply, i was looking in to it and fnd it quite helpful.  It changes the right part of an array as i intended, but i would like to print the path it takes for example when i+1 is 1 it prints right if i- 1 is 1 it prints left and if j + 1 is 1 it prints up and if j - 1 is 1 it prints down